# Session timeout using ini_set

Tags: php, session-cookies

I am trying to set the session expiry in PHP but when I run `phpinfo();` it's not reflecting the change

```
// server should keep session data for AT LEAST 1 hour
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600);

// each client should remember their session id for EXACTLY 1 hour
session_set_cookie_params(3600);

session_start();
```

I have had a look around, but can't seem to find what I've done wrong.

Comment: If you're running this locally, did you restart after making the change(s)?

Comment: i've restarted the apache2 service

Comment: Ok. Well, it's unclear as to why it's failing. Are you using any other code than what you posted? Have you checked for possible errors by checking your logs and/or enabling error reporting?

Comment: no errors display when enabling `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`, `ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);`, `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: @charlie Do you run `phpinfo();` on this PHP page where you have these `ini_set()` and `session_set_cookie_params()` calls or do you have `phpinfo();` on a different page where these calls are missing (and therefore not executed)?

Answer (score 1):

below code show me 5555 only in the output of `phpinfo`

```
// server should keep session data for AT LEAST 1 hour
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 5555);

// each client should remember their session id for EXACTLY 1 hour
session_set_cookie_params(5555);

phpinfo();
```